# UML State diagrams the correct way

Tags: uml, state-machine

What is the correct way to model a termination of a sub-state-machine in UML?

Lets say I have a sub state machine for some sort of agent that processes incoming events.
and lets say this state machine is called "processing"

Would it be valid to just draw a transition line from the "processing" machine to another state of the parent state machine?

e.g.

```
+SUB----------+                          +-----------+
| processing  |---user cancelled  ------>| done      |
+-------------+                          +-----------+
```

How would I show that the processing state machine terminates when the "user cancelled" trigger occurs?

Comment: looks okay, but here(in your diagram) `user cancelled` is kinda trigger(event), and as event definition, it means it will transfer into `done` if user cancels the operation and processing GETS FINISHED, I mean the trigger you(is) mentioned doesn't mean the termination rest of the work, you need to specify this event as an external event.

Answer (score 0):

Your modeling is OK. Your transition from `processing` to `done` is activated when `processing` is active and `user cancelled` is the current event. `processing` is active iff any of its substates, that is, any of the states in the submachine, is active. Therefore, the event `user cancelled` would stop the execution of the submachine, and the execution moves on to `done`.

Note if you only allow to cancel the execution of some (but not all) of the substates of `processing` (the submachine), then your state machine needs to be a little more involved. The event `user cancelled` would be too powerful if modeled as in your diagram.